# Hide the Rights of a user on windows

Tags: windows, administrator

Is there a way to conceal the fact that a user is an administrator to other users on Windows? For example, like the UserList tweak, the user will not show up in UAC as an administrator, but will still be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You MAY be able to prevent people from seeing the rights of other accounts, but it would require some real custom stuff if it was possible.

But no, Windows does not have a built in function to obscure the rights of other users on the system.